# `typedef T this_type` that doesn't require T

Tags: c++, c++11, typedef

Essentially, I need to know the current class so I can make macros that do things like:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<MyClass> sptr;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<const MyClass> csptr;
//etc
```

without having to put MyClass as a parameter to the macro. I've tried all sorts of ridiculous things like:

```
typedef decltype(*this) this_type;
```

but of course they don't work. Is there NOTHING that will let me work around this? I hoped C++11 would have given us something to hack together a way.

Comment: What is the "current class"? Where are you wanting to put this?

Comment: "_without having to put MyClass as a parameter to the macro_" -- Macro? What macro? Why are you using a macro? Just name the type, it's not that hard. Don't use the preprocessor to be lazy, it should be avoided when possible, it's [evil](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/preprocessor-is-evil.html)

Answer (score 3):

Two things: I would not make a fuss of having to repeat the type, and I would not use macros at all. You can use CRTP:

```
template <typename T>
struct sp_typedefs {
    typedef std::shared_ptr<T> sptr;         // [*]
    typedef std::shared_ptr<const T> csptr;
};
```

Then in each type use inheritance to bring the typedefs into your type:

```
class MyType : sp_typedefs<MyType>
{
   // ...
};
```

---

[*] Since you have tagged the question as C++11, you should be using `std::shared_ptr` which is standard, rather than `boost::shared_ptr`

Comment: He hasn't said what he's doing so I don't know if it's appropriate to try to answer the nebulous question.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: The question may be not clearly stated, but I believe it can inferred from the context. He wants to add typedefs to shared pointers to what seems to be the enclosing type (considering that he is trying to use `decltype(*this)`). Because that expression is not working this declarations cannot be inside a member function (where it would work), so my guess is that he wants to create typedefs inside the class definition. I could be wrong though :)

Comment: Yes, but I think he is making class definitions with macros or something and cannot use the class name, or he would have done it.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: He cannot or doesn't want to. Even if the class is defined with a macro you can repeat the name: `#define CREATE_CLASS(name) class name : public crtp<name> { ...` Note that the *name* must be used in the definition, so in the same way that it is used after the `class` or `struct` keyword, and in the same way that it is entered there it can be entered a couple of words later :)

Comment: Yep, but hopefully he is smart enough to already have noticed that and the problem lies elsewhere.